# regex - match words with hyphen only uppercase

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to match words that have more than 1 letter and: are all-upercase, first letter lowercase and following letters uppercase, or containing a hyphen in the middle ONLY if all the letters are uppercase. This is my code:

```
s = "ASCII, aSCII, AS-CII, AS-cii"

myset =   set(re.findall(r"\b[a-z]?[A-Z]+\-?[A-Z]{1,}",s))

Out[555]: {'AS', 'AS-CII', 'ASCII', 'aSCII'}
```

As you can see, the `"AS"` shouldn't be returned because it contains lower case letters after the hyphen. How could I fix this?

Tried this but the result is an error:

```
myset = set(re.findall(r"\b[a-z]?[A-Z]+\-?[A-Z]+{1,}",s))

  File "<ipython-input-545-7bdc0c902553>"
    myset = set(re.findall(r"\b[a-z]?[A-Z]+\-?[A-Z]+{1,}",s))

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 222, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))

  File "/home/c1962135/.local/share/virtualenvs/c1962135-9R_1M4TP/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 619, in _parse
    source.tell() - here + len(this))

error: multiple repeat
```

Comment: Is that acceptable for you to make 2 Regex ? One for all uPERLOWER,and one for UPER-UPER ???

Comment: @Skapin yes. I need to account for this in my task

Answer (score 0):

Here we are

```
res = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r"(([a-z]{1}[A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+))",s)]
print(res)
print(set(res))
```

gives

```
['aSCII', 'AS-CII']
```

Tell me. I splitted to add OR logic with | between.

Comment: No need cto escape the `-` here. And what about `ASCII` ?

Comment: That looks good... is there a way to make it without the tuples? Jan's comment is valid too.

Comment: I dont think so, but it's not important, the comprehension list give you the wanted output

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *conditional expression*:

```
(...)?(if true than this|else this)
```

For your case, this could be

```
\b([a-z])?(?(1)[A-Z]+|[-A-Z]+[A-Z])(?!-)\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Y3mz1D/1).

---

Broken down this reads

```
\b               # a word boundary
([a-z])?         # match a lower case letter if it is there
(?(1)            # if the lower case letter is there, match this branch
    [A-Z]+
|
    [-A-Z]+[A-Z] # else this one
)
(?!-)\b          # do not break at a -, followed by another boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches all of the mentioned critera:

```
\b[a-z]*[A-Z]+[\-A-Z]+[A-Z]+\b
```

Please check here https://regex101.com/r/JNC4kN/1/

But this will fail if you give this type of example like aTH-THTH (small letter following hyphen and uppercase). If you want only UPPER-UPPER then follow this regex:

```
\b[a-z]{0,1}(?<!\-)[A-Z]+\b(?!\-)|\b[A-Z]+\-[A-Z]+\b
```

check [here](https://regex101.com/r/JNC4kN/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression, which covers edge cases having to do with the word preceded by or followed by a hyphen (as shown at the link below):

```
(?<!\w|(?<=\w)-)(?:[a-zA-Z][A-Z]+|[A-Z]{2,}|[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+)(?!\w|-(?=\w))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR8iW8/2/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<!              # begin a negative lookbehind
  \w              # match word char
  |               # or
  (?<=\w)         # match a word char in a positive lookbehind
  -               # match '-'
)                 # end negative lookbehind
(?:               # begin non-cap grp
  [a-zA-Z][A-Z]+  # match a lc letter then 1+ uc letters
  |               # or
  [A-Z]{2,}       # match 2+ uc letters
  |               # or
  [A-Z]+-[A-Z]+   # match 1+ uc letters, '-', then 1+ uc letters
)                 # end non-cap grp
(?!               # begin negative lookahead
  \w              # match word char
  |               # or
  -               # match '-'
  (?=\w)          # match a word char in a positive lookahead
)                 # end negative lookahead
```